# How do I find out with jQuery if an element is being animated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm trying to move some elements on the page, and during the time the animation occurs, I want to have "overflow:hidden" applied to an elemnt, and "overflow" back to "auto" once the animation is completed.

I know jQuery has an utility function that determines whether some element is being animated but I can't find it anywhere in the docs

Answer (score 204, accepted):

```
if( $(elem).is(':animated') ) {...}
```

**More info**: https://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/

---

Or:

```
$(elem)
    .css('overflow' ,'hidden')
    .animate({/*options*/}, function(){
        // Callback function
        $(this).css('overflow', 'auto');
    };
```

Comment: yes that was it, thanks. how could I miss it? damn, I'm getting old

Comment: FYI, if you don't want to risk overwriting your CSS styles by programming "overflow: auto" in the callback, simply use `.css('overflow', '')`. Passing an empty string generally removes that property from the element's style altogether. Not sure if this is documented behavior, but it's a very useful trick.

Comment: I don't think it supports CSS animations.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, to test if something is not animated, you can simply add a "!":

```
if (!$(element).is(':animated')) {...}
```

Comment: This is very not true... The opposite of jquery 'is' is not 'not'.
'not' removes filtered elements from the jquery object.
If you want to check for not animated object you do `if (!$(element).is(':animated')) {...}`

Comment: @amosmos The answer was edited and community approved.. I have rolled it back to where it was correct.

Comment: @amosmos stop trolling

Answer (score 3):

if you are using `css` animation and assign the animation by using specific `class name`, then you can check it like this:

```
if($("#elem").hasClass("your_animation_class_name")) {}
```

But make sure that you are removing the class namewhich is handling the animation, after the animation is finished!

This code can be used to remove the `class name` after the animation is finished:

```
$("#elem").on('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend',
function(){ 
        $(this).removeClass("your_animation_class_name");
});
```

Comment: OP is using jQuery animaiton.

Comment: just suggesting an alternative. And did you meant animation?

Comment: Yes, I meant animation. IMO your answer is completely off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply css to animated elements, you can use the `:animated` pseudo selector and do it like this,

```
$("selector").css('overflow','hidden');
$("selector:animated").css('overflow','auto');
```

source : https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('selector').click(function() {
  if ($(':animated').length) {
    return false;
  }

  $("html, body").scrollTop(0);
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.