# Determining if JQuery effects are still executing

Tags: jquery, selenium, cucumber, capybara

For running Cucumber specs with Capybara and Selenium, I need to be able to determine if certain JQuery effects have completed before I can continue with the next step. Is there a generic way to determine if JQuery is still executing effects (e.g. something like `$.effects.active.size == 0`)?

Comment: checking ":animated" selector? http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can check if element is used by some animation plugin/feature via checking `:animated` selector

according to this: http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/

like this:

```
$("#el").is(":animated")
```

more info: 
[How do I find out with jQuery if an element is being animated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724911/how-do-i-find-out-with-jquery-if-an-element-is-being-animated)

Comment: Yes! And `$(":animated").length == 0` will then determine if all animations have finished. Very cool. Thanks, Marek.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative option (maybe it will suit somebody else needs), it's possible to completely disable the animations on page (until the is refreshed) by applying:

```
$('body').append('<style> * {transition: none!important;}</style>')
```

Comment: This is very useful to speed up the execution of automatic tests

Comment: @vcRobe That's exactly the reason we use it :)