# jquery divelement animates repetitivly on scroll action

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, fadein, repeat

I have this function:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('.scrollup').fadeIn('slow', function() {
            $('.cartinfo').animate({'right': '+=46px'}, 'slow');
        });
    } else {
        $('.scrollup').fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $('.cartinfo').animate({'right': '-=46px'}, 'slow');
        });
    }
});
```

The div with the class should anminate +46px if the scrollup fades in and -46 on fade out.

But it fires the animation on every scroll action i do.

Do you have a solution for this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Right now you have the `fade` and `animate` calls bound to every scroll action. You'll need to figure out when exactly you want them to fire, as every scroll action is clearly not the right time.

One solution is you could check to see if the element is currently being animated before firing a new animation, using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724911/how-do-i-find-out-with-jquery-if-an-element-is-being-animated) similar question as a guide.