# How To detect the show animation[jquery] is currently running

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show

i using show in jquery with specific time

```
$('#main_div').hide();
$('#main_div').show(3000);
```

is their any jquery selector to detect show animation is currntly running. is it possible???

Comment: I think this is what you are asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724911/how-do-i-find-out-with-jquery-if-an-element-is-being-animated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could check:

```
if( $("#main_div").is(':animated') ) {
   ...
}
```

See: [animated](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/animated)

Answer (score 1):

You can detect **whether an animation is running** by `:animated` selector, but it's not possible to decide **which animation is running**