# Delay on a function jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a hover effect with jquery on a menu, it works fine but if you move the mouse over the items a few times faster the animation then goes on as much times you got in that zone, sorry if I can't explain my problem as I wish, what I need is some kind of delay so if you move the mouse lots of times the function will trigger just one time and then you wait like 1sec for get the effect again. thanks!

```
$(".border").hover(function(){
    if($(this).next('.sous_menu').is(':visible')){
        $('.sous_menu').closest('.border').removeClass('border').addClass('border_active');
    }else{
        $(this).toggleClass('border_active border', 500);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xb8Ss/9/

Comment: You could check whether the element is animating: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724911/how-do-i-find-out-with-jquery-if-an-element-is-being-animated

Comment: Probably, you should use `.stop()` function to stop animation before reactivating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a `delay()` and stop() before the toggle.
The `stop()` will stop any ongoing animation preventing virtually endless animation. while the `delay()` will delay it for how many milliseconds you put.

```
$(this).stop()delay(1000).toggleClass('border_active border', 500);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look to this plugin : [hoverIntent jQuery Plug-in](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) as describe in this question [Delay jquery hover event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435732/delay-jquery-hover-event?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the function has been executed the last second by adding a checker var and chaning it on a timeout:

```
// the first time should always be allowed
var allow = true

$(".border").hover(function(){

    // if 'allow' is false, return without doing anything
    if(!allow) {
        return;
    }

    // the function is now gonna execute, don't allow
    // other events from executing the function
    allow = false;


    // executing the function
    if($(this).next('.sous_menu').is(':visible')){
        $('.sous_menu').closest('.border').removeClass('border').addClass('border_active');
    }else{
        $(this).toggleClass('border_active border', 500);
    }


    // after a second of the execution of the function, set allow to
    // true again to allow other events from executing the function
    setTimeout(function() {
        allow = true
    }, 1000)

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question properly, I believe this is what you're looking for...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var canMove = true;

    $("#moveme").hover(function() {
        if(canMove) {
            canMove = false;

            $(this).css("left", "50px");
            setTimeout(function() { canMove = true; }, 1000);
        }
    }, function() {
        $(this).css("left", "10px");
    });
});
```

jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/J5VAr/)

The on hover code above will only run once the "cooldown" of 1000 (1 second) has been reached.  Alternativly, you could have the set `canMove` to true on the hover exit, this would make sure that the code only runs once per hover (even though this should already be the case).