# fadeIn() doesn't work but fadeOut() is ok

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a fadeIn() and a fadeOut() to my scrollToTop but the fadeIn is'nt worked.

If you want ot see, I've created some GIF : [First GIF Here](https://i.gyazo.com/d1ccdcc1e616a0469b6e5e18d28c140c.gif)

[Seconde GIF](https://gyazo.com/6c5255b3a9d014860f4d8cfc16cfd42b)

As you can see the fadeIn() on the scrollToTop button is 
triggered by the scroll of the windows,

This is my code :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
  $('.modal-content').scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
      $(".scrollToTop").fadeIn(1000);
    } else {
      $('.scrollToTop').fadeOut(1000);
    }
  });

  //Click event to scroll to top
  $('.scrollToTop').click(function() {
    $('.modal-content').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 500);
    return false;
  });

});
```

```html
<a id="up" class="scrollToTop" style="display:none;"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

Comment: Please check the guidance in "[mcve]". A minimal repro would make it a lot easier and pleasant to help. (Which also would make gifs from a domain like "gyazo.com" superfluous.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert at jQuery, but it looks to me as though your problem resides in you invoking `fadeIn` nearly every time the page is scrolled. What I suggest is that you create a boolean, called `buttonShowing` (or whatever), and set it to false.

Then, change `buttonShowing` every time the user scrolls, at the end of the appropriate if and else statements. Then, at the beginning of the if/else statements, you can check if the `buttonShowing` state has changed and only fadeIn/Out if the state has changed since the last scroll event fired. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var buttonShowing = false;
  //Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
  $('.modal-content').scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
      if(!buttonShowing) $(".scrollToTop").fadeIn(1000);
      buttonShowing = true;
    } else {
      if(buttonShowing) $('.scrollToTop').fadeOut(1000);
      buttonShowing = false;
    }
  });

  //Click event to scroll to top
  $('.scrollToTop').click(function() {
    $('.modal-content').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 500);
    return false;
  });

});
```

Comment: You can use `.is(':animated')` rather than store your own bool.  Might not be as efficient, but then should probably *debounce* the onscroll handler anyway. http://stackoverflow.com/a/725282/2181514

Comment: @freedomn-m Cool. As I said, not a jQuery expert :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Best Solution for you:**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
    var scroll_div = $('.modal-content').offset().top;

    if(scroll_pos > scroll_div) {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100)
            $(".scrollToTop").fadeIn(1000);
        else
            $('.scrollToTop').fadeOut(1000);
    }
});
```

or Change `$('.modal-content').scroll(function() {` to `$(window).scroll(function() {`. See:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $(".scrollToTop").fadeIn(1000);
            } else {
            $('.scrollToTop').fadeOut(1000);
        }
    });

    //Click event to scroll to top
    $('.scrollToTop').click(function() {
        $('.modal-content').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 500);
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: I've tried your answer but it doesn't work, I think the "$(window).scroll(function() {"  is not coreecte because I work in a modal. If you want to see all the code of my page (with the modal, I make an anwer with it)

Comment: @Jerem: Use the `Best Solution for you`. Work as desired in the scroll div.

Answer (score 0):

This example may help you. :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                height: 1200px;
            }
            div {
                width: 50px;
                height: 50px;
                background-color: red;
                border-radius: 100%;
                position: fixed;
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="cir"></div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(window).scroll(function(){
                if($(document).scrollTop()>100)
                    $("#cir").fadeIn(1000);
                else
                    $("#cir").fadeOut(800);
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution with $(window).scroll(function()  doesn't work, certainly beacause this script is used on a modal.

This is an of my HTML code with the modal :

```html
<!-- Modal Structure -->
<div id="modal1" class="modal modal-fixed-footer">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <!-- My content -->
        <h4>Ajouter une recette</h4>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s6 offset-s3">
                <input id="libelle" type="text" class="validate">
                <label for="libelle">Nom de la recette</label>
            </div>            
        </div>
        <form id="form_ingredient">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col s4 offset-s1 input-field">
                    <input id="ingredient" name="ingredient" type="text" class="validate">
                    <label for="ingredient">Ingredient</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col s4 offset-s2 input-field">
                    <input id="poid" name="poid" type="number" class="validate">
                    <label for="poid">Poid</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer" style="text-align: right;">
        <!-- My footer -->
        <a id="up" class="scrollToTop" style="display:none;"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <a id="add_ing"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <a id="valid_ing" style="margin-left: 1.5%;"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
//The script that I try to use
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem with Css, I just add these class to my stylesheet :

```
.scrollToTop{
opacity:0;
text-decoration: none;
transition:opacity 1s ease-in;
float: left; }

.scrollToTop.visible {
opacity:1; }
```

And this Js and that works :

```
 $('.modal-content').scroll(function(){

        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {

                $(".scrollToTop").addClass('visible').css("cursor", "pointer");
        } else {
                $('.scrollToTop').removeClass('visible').css("cursor", "default");
        }
});
```